# Write event handler function in one line

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

I have this function to submit form,

```
function submitEvent()
{
    // setter for dom element
    document.forms[0].method = "POST";
    document.forms[0].action = "MyServlet";    
    document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

Now I have read about unobtrusive JS but I would like to add to a legacy markup.
How would I attach this function to an onclick attribute in a single line?
onclick =
I want it of the form,

`onclick = "myOneLineSubmitFunction()"`

Edit: Apologise for not giving the complete details. I want to bind it on the click event of the button. Code is:

`<input type="button" onclick="oneLineFunc();">`

Comment: Are you asking how to add an onclick event? Baic code is `document.getElementById("foo").onclick = submitEvent;`

Comment: Would something like this work and is a good choice? `onclick = " javascript: document.forms[0].method = "POST";
    document.forms[0].action = "MyServlet";    
    document.forms[0].submit();"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just want to set the onclick event handler of the element in question to the function.

```
document.getElementById('foo').onclick = submitEvent;
```